# Is there a way to skip the intro screens in American McGee's Alice?

Tags: american-mcgees-alice

Is there something I can add to the command line that will let me skip past all the intro screens and straight to the game menu?

Answer (score 1):

http://noctalis.com/dis/alice/eden2k.shtml

You just need to start the game with "alice.exe +forcemenu main" (after enabling the console).

Comment: Any other way to accomplish this in the console ports that you know of (since this obviously isn't an option)?

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of my brother, to skip the intro, start the game with `+forcemenu main`. You can do this by:

- Making a shortcut off of Alice.exe
- Right click on it -> go to properties
- where it says Target, put `+forcemenu main`, for example:

```
?:\EA GAMES\American McGee's Alice\Alice.exe" +forcemenu main
```

You can also use a .bat file in much the same way.